# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have developed a service with vb.net.
 
This service is been installed from a windows application which close immediately after the Service starts.
Inside the service I have a procedure “Protected Overrides Sub OnCustomCommand
“, this procedure works fine until the pointer comes to instruction which I give you below:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCustomCommand(ByVal command As Integer)
                StartLogFile("Custom Command {" & command & "} invoked", EventLogEntryType.Information)
                Dim Position As String
                Dim myFile As String = Nothing
                Dim myTime As String = Nothing
                Try
                    If command = SimpleServiceCustomCommands.StartWorker Then
                        Position = "GetKeyValue Time"
                        myTime = GetKeyValue("Time", "", RegPath)
                        Position = "GetKeyValue Name"
                        myFile = GetKeyValue("Name", "", RegPath)
                        StartLogFile("Notice OnCustomCommand" & vbNewLine & "MyTime= { " & myTime & "}, {MyFile= { " & myFile & "} ", EventLogEntryType.Error)
    .
    .
    .
    Catch ex As Exception
                    StartLogFile("Error OnCustomCommand" & vbNewLine & Position & vbNewLine & ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error)
                Finally
                End Try
```

I made some changes according to notices i read and now the **GetKeyValue** did not returns me any error. But either did not returns me any value.

The function Get is as follows:

```
Public Function GetKeyValue(ByVal nKey As String, ByVal vKey As String, ByVal sPath As String) As String
        Dim RegKey As RegistryKey
        Dim kValue As String = Nothing
        Dim Pos As String
        If RegKeyExists(sPath) Then
            Try
                RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(sPath, True)
                kValue = CStr(RegKey.GetValue(nKey))
            Catch ex As Exception
                StartLogFile(" GetKeyValue, RegKeyExists(sPath) " & vbNewLine & "{ RegKey= " & RegKey.Name & "}, { kValue= " & kValue & "}, { nKey= " & nKey & "}" & vbNewLine & "Stack Trace= " & ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Warning)
            End Try
        End If
        Return kValue
    End Function
```

Now what I have is:
**No Error, No Values** 
!!!!

Comment: Your select case looks wierd when it selects on a boolean variable.  Normally you'd use an if-statement for that...

Comment: @Stephen: what if you need to add `case FILE_NOT_FOUND`?

Comment: `true`, `false`, `FILE_NOT_FOUND`? Always thought the only other state was `null` (in the case of a tri-state/nullable boolean). The approach is still not future-proof using this approach.

Comment: @MusiGenesis, in this case probably return a boolean and throw a FILE_NOT_FOUND exception when the registry cannot be found -- if the user gets that, then the exception should be the least of his worry!  :-)

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code obviously didn't fail inside the try-catch statement inside GetKeyValue() because then you'll see from the log that the error came from inside that function itself.

So your code must be either be failing on the "False" case, or form the StartLogFile() call in the "True" case's catch block.

### False Case

Notice that you have `RegKey.Name` in your log statement, and `RegKey` is very obviously `null` because you never set it (it is only set in the True case).  I think this is where your error is.

### True Case Catch Block

The catch block in your "True" case does not access any property of any variable that may be null.  However, StartLogFile may itself be failing with such an execption *inside*.

### Swapped statements

I have a feeling that you have swapped the two StartLogFile() calls (the False case one should be in the catch block of the True case, and the one in the catch block of the True case should be in the False case).

### Avoid error logging that may itself fail

Also, even in the True case block, you cannot assume `RegKey` is non-null because `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey` may fail and you'll not understand where the error is because your try-catch block catches the fault and the it fails on your error logging statement instead!  This type of bug can be very frustrating to find, especially in large systems.  The morale: never make your error logging code too complex -- if they fail, they make it difficult to find out what happened.

### Always include stack trace in error log

Also, is there any reason why you don't include a stack trace in your error logging?  Having a stack trace will immediately pin-point you to the problem code line.

Comment: But the call to the method is scoped within a `try/catch`, too, so you could apply the same reasoning. And in the first case `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey` could return an invalid entity to call `RegKey.GetValue(nKey)` on, I'm not 100%.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment -- good find.  StartLogFile may be failing in the catch block as well.  I am wrong to assume that the exception is caught that it doesn't come from there.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Stephen: I deleted my comment to the original answer due to not being entirely sure, but we're also lacking the code for `RegKeyExists` itself, as well as `StartLogFile` - these may be helpful! Also maybe recommend in your answer that the OP drop the `try/catch` mechanisms for now, as part of the debugging process. :) ..ah, you kind of did in your update - good job, nice answer.

Comment: @Stephen: I made some changes according to your notices, please review my question

Comment: In GetKeyValue, kValue is returned.  kValue is only set to the result of "nKey" under the registry entry.  So my guess is that this key is null. But have you also checked that there is no log entry? If your code drops into the catch block, you'll still have kValue as null.

Comment: @Stephen. `vKey` is not used here it comes from another code. So we can ommited. Let me check for all the others because i suspect something going wrong here.

Comment: I can see that you have not learnt from my answer.  You are still using RegKey.Name in your catch block.  Obviously you are assuming that the OpenSubKey call *must* succeed, which is not guaranteed.  It may fail (in that case RegKey is null), or it may return null (in that case RegKey is also null).  Dropping into the catch block will then raise a new exception in your catch block because your call to StartLogFile will fail.

Comment: In that case, just print out RegKey.Name right after OpenSubKey, and print out kValue right after the call to GetValue.

Comment: @Stephen. I don't have any errors now but also i'm geting any price out. When the service works fine i'll delete all these lines.

Comment: @Stephen. Please look at my next question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be passing an invalid path to the registry key you want (`RegPath`).  In your `GetKeyValue` function, if `RegKeyExists` returns `False`, then the call to `StartLogFile` references `RegKey` which is still `Null` at this point - hence the error you're getting.

In that line, replace `RegKey.Name` with `sPath` and you should at least then see the original error in your log file.  Or just make sure you have the correct path.

Comment: The path is correct because the respond from the `If`statement is `True`. Additionally I made some changes in my code and run it again and of course I have another reaction in my service.